# magit status and git lfs files diff shows pointer diff

Tags: magit, git

When I call `magit-status` git lfs files are shown as follows.

```
modified   src/myfile
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
-oid sha256:ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
-size 4241
+oid sha256:9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
+size 4242
```

Is it possible to tell magit to show me the diff of the contents instead of the lfs-pointers' diff?

Comment: There's a `magit-lfs` package on Melpa. Why don't you give it a try and see what it does?

Comment: I have it installed already :) but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58508020/7535684) I found my answer. The command `git config diff.lfs.textconv cat` does the trick for me. Even though as mentioned by tarsius, this comes with a significant slowdown, that's what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Magit itself does not support this and I think it probably should not.

In any case, you can probably tell `git diff` itself to display these differently and since Magit just uses `git diff` that would affect it too.

It seems reasonable for `git` to *not* display diffs for lfs files; after all lfs is intended for huge files whose diffs are not useful and/or huge. If you manage to display the diffs, that could come with a significant slowdown.